# Python regex difficulties

Tags: python, regex

This might be a simple one :)
I am try to turn convert the following:

```
<gallery>File:ReDescribe.jpg|Photo by:J. K.File:redescribe_still1.pngFile:redescribe_still2.jpegFile:redescribe_still3.jpgFile:redescribe_still4.jpgFile:redescribe_still5.jpg</gallery>
```

into:

```
[[File:ReDescribe.jpg|photo by: J K]][[File:redescribe_still1.png]] [[File:redescribe_still2.jpeg]] [[File:redescribe_still3.jpg]] [[File:redescribe_still4.jpg]] [[File:redescribe_still5.jpg]]
```

And to start with I am looking for a Python regex that can selects only each File:filename.ext

So far I though of `'File:(.*?)File'`  but this expression excludes the last File: since it is not followed any character.
See it regex_tester https://regex101.com/r/iV1mD9/1

How could the expression also match the last File: which is followed by `</gallery>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File:(.*?)(?=File:|<\/gallery>)
```

Try this.See demo.Use `lookahead` to make sure last `File:` is also captured.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/94#python

Comment: lookhead - something from regex I still need to study. Thaks @vks and @ Avinash Raj

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `gallery` tag and then apply the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
>>> s = '''<gallery>File:ReDescribe.jpg|Photo by:J. K.File:redescribe_still1.pngFile:redescribe_still2.jpegFile:redescribe_still3.jpgFile:redescribe_still4.jpgFile:redescribe_still5.jpg</gallery>'''
>>> re.sub(r'(File:.+?)(?=File:|$)', r'[[\1]]', re.sub(r'</?gallery>', '', s))
'[[File:ReDescribe.jpg|Photo by:J. K.]][[File:redescribe_still1.png]][[File:redescribe_still2.jpeg]][[File:redescribe_still3.jpg]][[File:redescribe_still4.jpg]][[File:redescribe_still5.jpg]]'
```